# Ordinal captions of figures with Basque-Babel in tufte-book

Tags: captions, babel, tufte

Basque numbering of figures and tables must be ordinal but Babel implementation produces them as in English or Spanish: *Irudia 1* instead of **1. irudia**.

```
\documentclass[]{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[basque]{babel}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My problem with captions in Basque\&Babel}

In Basque, a language spoken in the north of Spain and the South of France, it is stated that the numbering of tables and figures must be done using ordinal numbers \textit{1. irudia} and \textit{1. taula}

\begin{figure}[ht]
%http://digital.uncg.edu/390/jennifer_hutchens/images/tufte.jpg
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{tufte.jpg}
\caption{\textit{The man.}}
\end{figure}

The caption of the tables should be exactly the same but\ldots

\begin{table}
 \small
 \centering
 \fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
  \toprule
Akzio motor eremua & N &  \\
 \midrule
Kirol psikomotorrak & 115 & \%47\\
Kirol soziomotorrak & 130 & \%53 \\
  \midrule
\textit {Guztira}& \textit {245} & \textit {\%100} \\
  \bottomrule \bigskip
\end{tabular}

\caption{\textit{1984 urteko Joko Olinpikoetako kirolak.}}
\end{table}

Any ideas? Thank you all.

Raul MdSG.

\today. (9/28/2016)

\end{document}
```

This chunk of code results as follows: [Basque captions in tufte-book with babel](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5480715/BasqueTufte/BasqueCaptions.pdf)

Any ideas? Thank anyone in advance.

RMdSG

Answer (score 3):

The label formats are controlled by internal macros `fnum@figure` and `fnum@table`.  You can redefine them to print "number. name" in the following way

```
\makeatletter
\def\fnum@figure{\thefigure.\nobreakspace\figurename}
\makeatother
```

etc.  As you only want this for one particular language you should include the `\def` lines inside the `\extras...` macro for that language.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=basque]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\addto\extrasbasque{%
  \def\fnum@figure{\thefigure.\nobreakspace\figurename}%
  \def\fnum@table{\thetable.\nobreakspace\tablename}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{My problem with captions in Basque \& Babel}

In Basque, a language spoken in the north of Spain and the South of 
France, it is stated that the numbering of tables and figures must be
done using ordinal numbers \textit{1. irudia} and \textit{1. taula}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-a}
\caption{\textit{The man.}}
\end{figure}

The caption of the tables should be exactly the same but\ldots

\begin{table}
 \small
 \centering
 \fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
  \toprule
Akzio motor eremua & N &  \\
 \midrule
Kirol psikomotorrak & 115 & \%47\\
Kirol soziomotorrak & 130 & \%53 \\
  \midrule
\textit {Guztira}& \textit {245} & \textit {\%100} \\
  \bottomrule \bigskip
\end{tabular}

\caption{\textit{1984 urteko Joko Olinpikoetako kirolak.}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```